# Remove Input styles from materializecss

Tags: html, css, materialize

is it poosible to remove all the Js and CSS linked to the input tag? im in need of removing all of them so that i can style them as i wish.

Comment: just open inspector in browser and research what  you want to change

Answer (score 1):

I checked it out. Unfortunately Materialize.css provides Input & Select components in Forms.css & Forms.js

```
// In Rails, we include like this
----------------------------------------------
CSS :
@import "materialize/components/form";

JS :
//= require materialize/forms
```

*But they have other elements as well.* **Your best way is to override the existing properties in your own global CSS file.**

-------------------------------------------------------- Edit ----------------------------------------------

Yes you can include only the components which you need from materialize.css. I could show how to **include materialize partially** but I don't know your tech-stack

-- OR --

You can define your own CSS and override the properties that differ from materialize CSS properties

```
input[type=text]{
   color : red;
   line-height : 1.5;
}
```

Comment: i believe it is done through SASS am i wrong? could you show me if you dont mind. just need to remove the select and input css.

Comment: @UmarGora Check updated answer. Override the values. It works well like that and is the right way to do.

Comment: everyone knows that removing CSS do the work, the point it's don't have to do this every materializecss update, so framework shouldn't use selectors like "input"s (bad practice), should use class selectors.